# ReplyTo email address using Visualforce email templates but sending through apex

Tags: apex, email, email-template, visualforce

I have been working on creating a Visualforce page that allows you to choose users and send out emails to those users using apex.  The problem I have run into is that the email address that the user can reply to is not working properly.  The template I am using is a Visualforce email template which has the replyto email address already input into the template.  However, when I reply to the email sent from the apex code, it replies back to the sender, not the email address in the template.

I tried to include the setReplyTo() functionality in my apex, but I get an error when sending a Visualforce email template if I try to choose a replyto email in my apex.

Anyone have any ideas on how to get this working?  Let me know if you want me to show my code.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the reply-to address defined an a Organization-wide address? If so, be sure to set it `code`mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(replyAddress.Id);

Comment: We have an Organization-wide address, but I don't want to use that address for these emails.

Comment: And I would just add that address as a new Organization-wide address as that would be the easiest way to use it, but it's a noreply email address so I wouldn't be able to confirm the address anyways.